# Splitter aborts during exception with out processing subsequent messages

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-aws

I have a requirement to split the messages and process one by one. If any of the messages fails, I would like to report it to error channel and resume processing the next available messages

I am using spring cloud aws stream starter with 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

I wrote a sample program using splitter

```
     @Bean
      public MessageChannel channelSplitOne() {
        return new DirectChannel();
      }


      @StreamListener(INTERNAL_CHANNEL)
      public void channelOne(String message) {
        if (message.equals("l")) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Error due to l");
        }
        System.out.println("Internal: " + message);
      }


      @Splitter(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT, outputChannel = INTERNAL_CHANNEL)
      public List<Message> extractItems(Message<String> input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.getPayload().split(""))
            .map(s -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(s).copyHeaders(input.getHeaders()).build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
```

When I send the message as Hello, the exxpectation is that
    'h','e','o' shall be processed, but 'l' shall be reported as error.

But here the after 'l', the processing is not resumed.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but with the `@ServiceActivator` instead of `@StreamListener`. The first one has `adviceChain` option where you can inject an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice.

The problem that the splitter is like a regular loop in Java, so to continue after error we need to add somehow a try...catch there. But that’s already not a splitter responsibility. Therefore we have to move such a logic into the place we have a error problem.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure, if I need advice chain here. I also removed splitter. I am splitting message and manually posting to internal channel. I have used try catch and if there is any exception, I am manually creating errorMesage and sending to erroeChannel.

Comment: Well, then it’s not a Spring Integration solution. That’s something home made 